# Rails 3.2 + minitest + sqlite3 :memory: = Fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, minitest

I'm unable to use the :memory: database with Rails 3.2, sqlite3, and minitest.  I have the following in database.yml:

```
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: ":memory:"
```

and get the following error when doing `rake minitest`

```
/home/hoffmanc/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:465:in  `table_structure': Could not find table 'apks' (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
```

(one of my models is named Apk)

Am I missing a step?

Comment: Have you prepared your test database? `rake db:test:prepare`

Comment: What version of `minitest-rails` are you using?

Comment: @blowmage: I did try `rake db:test:prepare` , which did not solve the problem.  Now I'm just back on a regular-file database.  minitest-rails = 0.1.3

Comment: I've created he following issue for this. I'll answer this question when we have this working. https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails/issues/72